# Spring MVC Url Why do I get a 404 when I encode a linefeed in the url

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, encode

I am sending an url with certain parameters to my controller, which works generally fine. I am using javascript function encodeURI() to encode the parameter.

But as soon, as there is a linefeed, I receive a 404 error.

This is a working url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Weasy/virtualtable/execQuery/46/select%20*%20from%20payment
```

This is a non-working url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Weasy/virtualtable/execQuery/46/select%20*%20%0Afrom%20payment
```

And this is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("execQuery/{schema_id}/{query}")
public ModelAndView execQuery(
        @PathVariable("schema_id") Integer schemaId
      , @PathVariable("query") String query) throws Exception {

    SrcSchema schema = this.srcschemaService.getRowById(schemaId);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("virtualtable/form");
    mav.addObject("schema", schema);
    mav.addObject("query", query);


    try {
        int limit = 10;
        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcService.executeQuery(schema.getConnection(), query, limit);             
        mav.addObject("rows", rows);
        mav.addObject("message", "<span class='msg-info'>Result Set reduced to "+limit+" rows</span>");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error executing sql", ex);            
        mav.addObject("message", "<span class='msg-error'>"+ex.getMessage()+"</span>");

    }


    return mav;
}
```

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is your app. I guess it is your web server blocking the request as you are using an odd character. Apache for example denies the access to urls containing %2F (/), %5F (\) or %00 (NULL). As a rule, the ASCII characters between %00 and %1F, named control characters, should not be present at urls, and %0A is one of them.

My advice is you should parse your query and get rid of, not only %0A but also any problematic character, before doing the request.

If you still want to make it works I think you need to include a rewriterule in your .htaccess (I guess you are using Apache), and use a regular expression to remove the line feed and redirect to the same url without that character.

[Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)